Python ModuleNotFoundError with module in the same directory as the script
I'm having problems running a script I created in python on one of my machines
On the machine where I installed python "the normal way", via the installer, it runs as intended. On the machine where I installed a standalone version of python and manually added the python installation folder to the "Path" system variable it doesn't recognize the "src" module I created. (I'm using windows on both machines)
The src module is located in the same directory where I'm trying to run the script.
This is the file structure:
project/
    run_generator.py
    src/
        __init__.py
        generator.py

this is the run_generator.py content
import os
import traceback
from time import time

from src.generator import Generator

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        open_output_file = False  # Set to True to open the output file automatically, False otherwise
        sort_adm_type_to_field_keys = False  # Set to True to sort the match_adm_type_to_field keys, False otherwise

        script_path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
        script_dir = os.path.dirname(script_path)
        os.chdir(script_dir)

        start_time = time()

        generator = Generator(sort_adm_type_to_field_keys=sort_adm_type_to_field_keys)
        generator.generate_output(open_output_file=open_output_file)

        print(f"Execution time: {time() - start_time} seconds")
    except Exception as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        traceback.print_exc()

    if not os.getenv('PYCHARM_HOSTED'):
        input("Press Enter to exit")

To run the script I'm using this command: python run_generator.py
I'm running the command from the same directory where the script (run_generator.py) is located.
I'm getting this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Scripts\adm_inactivator_generator\run_generator.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.generator import Generator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'

Python should look for modules in the current directory right?
I'm not sure if the problem lies in the fact that I've manfully configured the system variable and didn't make any other configuration.
To configure python in the "Path" system variable I simply added the "D:\_Software\python-3.12.3" directory (the directory where python is installed).
Any idea why I'm having this issue?
Again, the same script runs perfectly on the machine where I've used the python installer to install python.
I've tried to run the script via the command prompt, powershell, directly with the default program, but nothing works.

Does this answer your question? Relative imports for the billionth time

As I said, it works on one machine, it just doesn't work on the other, even doe the directory structure is the same. Because of that, I think it's a problem of how I'm importing it.
